# ASP.net extra controls on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to list all controls on a page. 
I do it like so

```
protected void listControls(Control c)
{
    if (c.HasControls())
    {
        tb_message.Text += String.Format("{0}{1}", c.ID, System.Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (Control control in c.Controls)
        {
            tb_message.Text += String.Format("{0}{1}", control.ID, System.Environment.NewLine);
            listControls(control);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the output like this (+ an extra two empty lines at the beginning)

```
    form1

    tb_life_cycle

    tb_message

    btn_button
```

If I only have the following controls: tb_life_cycle, tb_message, btn_button + the form form1? Thank you

Comment: you have the same controls listed in the output as the controls you say you have in expected results. [Duplicate Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362482/c-sharp-get-all-web-controls-on-page)?

Comment: @user2936347 not clear what you want in output?

Comment: He's probably talking about the "(+ an extra two empty lines at the beginning)"

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why the extra empty lines

Comment: I only add a new line after the control ID, so why are the two empty lines at the beginning and also after every control ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Web Forms adds several controls to a Control collection so that it can render things like plain text (defined as part of the ASPX designer.) You'll probably find that the extra controls you weren't expecting as part of your output are `LiteralControl`s generated by ASP.NET.

Try also including the `Type` of each control as part of your output.

```
protected void listControls(Control c) {
    if (c.HasControls()) {
        litText.Text += String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", c.GetType(), c.ID, System.Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (Control control in c.Controls) {
            litText.Text += String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", control.GetType(), control.ID, System.Environment.NewLine);
            listControls(control);
        }
    }
}
```